# Minimum number of moves to reach a grid point by modified knight in variant chessboard

Tags: algorithms, knight-tours

I apologize if this is not the right board to post this question. I am dealing with a computational question that extends the question posed in [Minimum number of moves to reach a cell in a chessboard by a knight](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104700/minimum-number-of-moves-to-reach-a-cell-in-a-chessboard-by-a-knight) to the variant form of chess posed in [Knight move variant: Can it move from $A$ to $B$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/710815/knight-move-variant-can-it-move-from-a-to-b). Specifically, what is the number of minimum moves for a modified knight (call it ($\alpha,\beta$)-knight) that moves with $\pm\alpha$ and $\pm\beta$ along the coordinates (instead of the usual $[\pm 2, \pm 1]$)) in any direction to reach a point $(x, y)$ starting from the origin (0,0)? This would mean moving from $(x,y)$ to any of the following: (±$\alpha$,±$\beta$), (∓$\alpha$,±$\beta$), (±$\beta$,±$\alpha$) or (∓$\beta$,±$\alpha$) We can assume without loss of generality that $x \geq y$.

My initial thoughts of how to approach this is as follows:

1. Modify the equation to reach either the $x$-axis or the diagonal as well as the number of subsequent moves from the diagonal to reach the origin as solved in [Minimum number of moves to reach a cell in a chessboard by a knight](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104700/minimum-number-of-moves-to-reach-a-cell-in-a-chessboard-by-a-knight).
2. Solve this problem computationally with a recurrence equation that can be solved using dynamic programming (thought I suspect for larger$N$ in a $N\times N$ chessboard for large $\alpha$ and large $\beta$, this becomes intractable).
3. Use the logic behind the proof posted in [Knight move variant: Can it move from $A$ to $B$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/710815/knight-move-variant-can-it-move-from-a-to-b) to come up with an analytical solution for a recurrence equation rather than try to solve it computationally.
4. Graph approach using Dijkstra's algorithm akin to solution posted in [Chess knight move in 8x8 chessboard](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1585538/chess-knight-move-in-8x8-chessboard). Again, this may become computationally intractable unless this is solved using sparse graphs.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I would look into the limits of sum of indexes - as example (1,1) limits you to only even sum indexes  which means that you can not get to half the board.

Comment: @Moti that's an interesting thought. Another thing I thought about was taking into consideration the range of tiles visited to lie between lines $y = \frac{\alpha}{\beta}x$ and $y = \frac{\beta}{\alpha}x$.